# Cannot scan QR code using zbar

Tags: python, opencv, zbar

[My QR code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zclcr.png)

When I run my code I´m always getting "[]" as output, which means that Zbar can´t read the QR... There is something wrong with my image format? I can´t figure out why this is not working.

**My code:**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import zbar
import sys

class ImageSource(object):
    def __init__(self,source):
        self.is_camera = type(source)==int
        if self.is_camera:
            self.source = cv2.VideoCapture(source)
        else:
            self.source = cv2.imread(source,1)

    def get_size(self):
        if self.is_camera:
            return (int(self.source.get(3)),int(self.source.get(4)))
        else:
            return (self.source.shape[1],self.source.shape[0])

    def get_next(self):
        if self.is_camera:
            return self.source.read()[1]
        else:
            return self.source

    def release(self):
        if self.is_camera:
            self.source.release()

class QRScanner(object):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.scanner = zbar.ImageScanner()
        self.scanner.parse_config('enable')
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def get_qrcodes(self, image):
        zbar_img = self.cv2_to_zbar_image(image)
        self.scanner.scan(zbar_img)
        result=[]
        for symbol in zbar_img:
            if symbol.type!=zbar.Symbol.QRCODE: continue
            fixed_data = symbol.data.decode("utf8").encode("shift_jis").decode("utf8")

            result.append(QRCode(fixed_data,symbol.location))
        del(zbar_img)
        return result

    def cv2_to_zbar_image(self, cv2_image):
        return zbar.Image(self.width, self.height, 'Y800',cv2_image.tostring())


cap = ImageSource("1.png")
frame = cap.get_next()
scanner = QRScanner(cap.get_size()[0],cap.get_size()[1])
print scanner.get_qrcodes(frame)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the actual problem is, but I was able to get this working using Pil (or Pillow) instead of cv2.

```
import cv2
import Image
import zbar
import sys

class ImageSource(object):
    def __init__(self,source):
        self.is_camera = type(source)==int
        if self.is_camera:
            self.source = cv2.VideoCapture(source)
        else:
            self.source = cv2.imread(source,1)

    def get_size(self):
        if self.is_camera:
            return (int(self.source.get(3)),int(self.source.get(4)))
        else:
            return (self.source.shape[1],self.source.shape[0])

    def get_next(self):
        if self.is_camera:
            return self.source.read()[1]
        else:
            return self.source

    def release(self):
        if self.is_camera:
            self.source.release()

class QRScanner(object):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.scanner = zbar.ImageScanner()
        self.scanner.parse_config('enable')
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def get_qrcodes(self, image):
        zbar_img = self.cv2_to_zbar_image(image)
        self.scanner.scan(zbar_img)
        result=[]
        for symbol in zbar_img:
            if symbol.type!=zbar.Symbol.QRCODE: continue
            fixed_data = symbol.data.decode("utf8").encode("shift_jis").decode("utf8")

            result.append((fixed_data,symbol.location))
        del(zbar_img)
        return result

    def cv2_to_zbar_image(self, cv2_image):
        return zbar.Image(self.width, self.height, 'Y800',cv2_image.tostring())

pil = Image.open(sys.argv[1]).convert('L')
width, height = pil.size
scanner = QRScanner(width,height)
print scanner.get_qrcodes(pil)
```

Also, this didn't work with all QR codes I tried, but here was one that did work:

```
http://media.techtarget.com/rms/misc/qr_code_barcode.jpg
```

[image: working qr code for above]

Comment: Thanks, but I´m working with video stream, so I need to fix this with cv2

Comment: @abea that's fair, but maybe try with a QR that works with Pil(low) first so you know you should get results.  I tried with several images found via googling "QR image sample" and the first 2 or 3 didn't work at all.